# Dibujar un picturebox , dibujando lineas y uniendo puntos

Tags: c#, windows-forms, picturebox

Tengo un formulario con winForms y c# donde tengo definido dos picturebox y unos textbox que rellenando esos valores me genera un gráfico uniendo los puntos x1 --> x2 ...luego x2 --> x3 y asín sucesivamente.
El código que tengo es este.

En el evento **textChanged** de los textbox tengo este código

```
private void modificarDatos_Audio_OD_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           botonPintarGrafica_Click(null, null);
    }
```

Y en la función tengo lo siguiente

```
 private void botonPintarGrafica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0, multiplicador = 42;
        int x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0, x5 = 0;
        int y1 = 0, y2 = 0, y3 = 0, y4 = 0, y5 = 0;

        List<DibujoRXModel> listaPuntos = new List<DibujoRXModel>();
        DibujoRXModel tonoOD_A = new DibujoRXModel();


        tonoOD_A.pos1 = Convert.ToInt32(DataUtils.IntNullToZero(pos1a.Text));
        tonoOD_A.pos2 = Convert.ToInt32(DataUtils.IntNullToZero(pos2a.Text));
        tonoOD_A.pos3 = Convert.ToInt32(DataUtils.IntNullToZero(pos3a.Text));
        listaPuntos.Add(tonoOD_A);



        Graphics grafico1;
        grafico1 = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        grafico1.Clear(Color.LightGreen);



        Pen lapiz = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);

        foreach (DibujoRXModel tono in listaPuntos)
        {
            if (tono.pos1 >= 0)
            {
                x1 = 1 * multiplicador;
                y1 = tono.pos1;
                grafico1.DrawRectangle(lapiz, new Rectangle(x1, y1, 5, 5));
            }

            if (tono.pos2 >= 0)
            {
                x2 = 2 * multiplicador;
                y2 = tono.pos2;
                grafico1.DrawRectangle(lapiz, new Rectangle(x2, y2, 5, 5));
            }

            if (tono.pos3 >= 0)
            {
                x3 = 3 * multiplicador;
                y3 = tono.pos3;
                grafico1.DrawRectangle(lapiz, new Rectangle(x3, y3, 5, 5));
            }

        }


        grafico1.DrawLine(lapiz, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        grafico1.DrawLine(lapiz, x2, y2, x3, y3);        

    }
```

Esto lo que hace es que conforme voy cambiando los valores en los textbox va repintando el gráfico , el problema que tengo es que si me muevo con el mouse entre los textbox no pasa nada , pero si me muevo con el tabulador entre los textbox el gráfico "desaparece" y no veo el problema por donde viene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás dibujando en el `PictureBox` pero en el momento en el que el control se debe redibujar, se borra todo lo que hayas hecho. Para comprobarlo fijate que, una vez tienes el grafico en pantalla, si minimizas el formulario y lo vuelves a maximizar, tambien se borrará tu `PictureBox`.

Hay dos soluciones para el problema. Por un lado, en lugar de pintar en el control directamente, puedes pintar en una imagen y asignarsela a `PictureBox`.

La segunda solución es dibujar tu gráfica en el evento `Paint` del `PictureBox`. De esa manera, cada vez que el control deba redibujarse, tambien redibujará tu grafico. Sería algo asi:

- Evento `TextChanged` de tus textboxes:

  ```
  private void modificarDatos_Audio_OD_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       botonPintarGrafica_Click(null, null);
  }
  ```
- Evento `Click` del boton

  ```
  private void botonPintarGrafica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      pictureBox1.Invalidate(); //esto hace que se llame al evento Paint del PictureBox  
  }
  ```
- Evento `Paint` del PictureBox

  ```
  private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
      int x = 0, y = 0, multiplicador = 42;
      int x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0, x5 = 0;
      int y1 = 0, y2 = 0, y3 = 0, y4 = 0, y5 = 0;

      List<DibujoRXModel> listaPuntos = new List<DibujoRXModel>();
      DibujoRXModel tonoOD_A = new DibujoRXModel();

      tonoOD_A.pos1 = Convert.ToInt32(pos1a.Text.Trim().Length == 0 ? "0" : pos1a.Text);
      tonoOD_A.pos2 = Convert.ToInt32(pos2a.Text.Trim().Length == 0 ? "0" : pos2a.Text);
      tonoOD_A.pos3 = Convert.ToInt32(pos3a.Text.Trim().Length == 0 ? "0" : pos3a.Text);
      listaPuntos.Add(tonoOD_A);

      Graphics grafico1;
      grafico1 = e.Graphics; //OJO:obtenemos el grafico de los argumentos del evento
      grafico1.Clear(Color.LightGreen);

      Pen lapiz = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);

      foreach (DibujoRXModel tono in listaPuntos)
      {
          if (tono.pos1 >= 0)
          {
              x1 = 1 * multiplicador;
              y1 = tono.pos1;
              grafico1.DrawRectangle(lapiz, new Rectangle(x1, y1, 5, 5));
          }

          if (tono.pos2 >= 0)
          {
              x2 = 2 * multiplicador;
              y2 = tono.pos2;
              grafico1.DrawRectangle(lapiz, new Rectangle(x2, y2, 5, 5));
          }

          if (tono.pos3 >= 0)
          {
              x3 = 3 * multiplicador;
              y3 = tono.pos3;
              grafico1.DrawRectangle(lapiz, new Rectangle(x3, y3, 5, 5));
          }

      }


      grafico1.DrawLine(lapiz, x1, y1, x2, y2);
      grafico1.DrawLine(lapiz, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  }
  ```

Comment: Perfecto justo lo que necesitava. Muchas gracias por la explicación.