# ¿Cómo conservar el contenido de un PictureBox en VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

¡Buenas a todos!

Tengo un Datagridview con una información específica que al hacer clic en una fila muestra al costado derecho un especie de vista previa del ticket impreso, el problema es que cuando hago scroll en el control o lo saco de la pantalla el contenido del PictureBox (el área donde "dibujo" los datos) se borra.

El PictureBox está contenido dentro de un Panel para poder hacer el "scroll".

[image: Contenido del PictureBox se borra]

El siguiente es el código que realiza la tarea:

```
Private Sub data_grid_marcar_pedidos_cancelados_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles data_grid_marcar_pedidos_cancelados.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer

    i = data_grid_marcar_pedidos_cancelados.CurrentRow.Index

    ' Creando área de dibujo donde picture_area es el control PictureBox
    Dim g As Graphics = picture_area.CreateGraphics

    ' id pedido
    Dim id_pedido As Integer = data_grid_marcar_pedidos_cancelados.Item(0, i).Value

    [...]

    With g

        g.Clear(Color.White)

        ' Impresion del texto del local
        cadena_encabezado = "Jaleo Bar"

        ancho = .MeasureString(cadena_encabezado, drawfont_encabezado).Width
        punto_inicio_encabezado = 10
        .DrawString(cadena_encabezado, drawfont_encabezado, drawBrush, punto_inicio_encabezado, 30)

        [...]

        ' Total
        .DrawString("TOTAL", drawfontbold, drawBrush, margen_totales_titulos, espaciado_datos)
        ancho = .MeasureString(Format(total, "N2"), drawfont).Width
        punto_inicio_totales = 285 - ancho

        .DrawString(Format(total, "N2"), drawfontbold, drawBrush, punto_inicio_totales, espaciado_datos)

        picture_area.Height = espaciado_datos
    End With
End Sub
```

**Nota:** Si se requiere poner todo el código, lo hago, no hay ningún problema.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas usando un objeto graphics, que es volatil a la hora de moverlo, porque no dibuja sobre un contenido. Tal vez deberias usar un canvas? no sabria como resolver tu problema si no.. la otra es que si es solo texto, uses un textbox...

Comment: @gbianchi por requerimiento debo mostrar el ticket tal y como se va a imprimir, lo de canvas no lo había pensado. Lo intentaré y comentaré el resultado. Gracias por tu pronta ayuda.

Comment: Si quieres que se mantenga lo que dibujas en el Picturebox, lo que debes hacer es dibujarlo en el evento `Paint` del `Picturebox`.Puedes revisar [esta respuesta que di hace un tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/73976/15301)

Comment: @Pikoh gracias, lo he hecho como explicas y efectivamente el contenido se conserva, pero con el inconveniente de que ahora se produce una especie de parpadeo en el texto. Tu comentario me dio una pista de como solucionarlo, cuando lo solucione publicaré el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contestando a mi propia pregunta y agradeciendo a @Pikoh lo pude solicionar cambiando:

```
' Creando área de dibujo donde picture_area es el control PictureBox
Dim g As Graphics = picture_area.CreateGraphics
```

por

```
' Creando área de dibujo, 
Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(310, 800)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)

' Una vez realizado todos los gráficos se asigna el objeto Bitmap a la propiedad Image del Control PictureBox
picture_area.Image = bm
```

Así al desplazarme hacia abajo o sacar de la pantalla el formulario el contenido no se pierde.

[image: PictureBox no borra imagen]